# hibernate - сохранение объекта, имеющего OneToMany

Tags: hibernate, java

Есть две таблицы А и Б.

У Б есть поле a_id внешний ключ на А

Класс А имеет список элементов Б.

Сохраняю А:
session.save(a);

В консоль выходит следующее:

```
insert to A
insert to B
insert to B
insert to B
....
update B....
update B....
update B....
update B....
.....
```

Не понимаю, почему происходят апдейты, смотрю что апдейтит... те же самые значения :(
Если список элементов Б большой, скажем N, то кол-во запросов при сохранении А: 1+N+N

Кто-нибудь знает в чем проблема?

Код:

класс А содержит:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="a_fk", nullable = false)
    private List<B> list;
```

класс Б содержит только

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну а чего вы хотели то? Это же каскадные обновления: плата за лень. Вы определили foreign key как cascade, что означает что система будет сама обеспечивать целостность данных, а делает она это туповато.

Почитайте мануалы к SQL по-поводу каскадных обновлений/удалений и referential integrity.

P.S. Надеюсь, вы понимаете что Hibernate к этому отношения не имеет.

Comment: Не очень хорошо разбираюсь в хибернейт(
А есть другие варианты сохранить а + его список?

Comment: Не согласен. Вставки данных в таблицы в этом случае вполне достаточно. Зачем далее идут апдейты - непонятно. К сожалению не разбираюсь в хибернейте, так что не могу помочь.